# Fields from CiviGrant as tokens?

Tags: tokens, civigrant

What is the best way of getting fields from grants available as tokens for mail/PDF-merge?

No native tokens?
Not available in form processor extension?

Answer (score 1):

If the tokens for grants are not available in core (which I can imagine) and appartently the data-processor tokens extension does not work with them either, the option you have left is to create an extension that adds them as custom tokens.

Comment: or add to https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.civitoken